# Tamgotchi like app day/night cycle

Tags: android, calendar

To learn android I'm making a tamagotchi like app. Its food lvl decreases 1 every hour so if you dont feed it for some hours it dies. I also have that between 8pm and 8am its asleep. Only there is a problem. To change its state to sleeping you need to open the app between 8pm and 8am. That gives the following problem:

If you feed it, lets say at 7pm, 1 hour before it sleeps, and you dont open the app between 8pm and 8 am but at 9am the following day he thinks 13 hours have elapsed instead of 1 (he shouldnt count the sleeping hours) Do you guys ahve any tips?

this is the sleepy and decay code

```
public void checkSleepyTime()
{
    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int daypart = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    if (hour >= 20 && daypart == 1)
    {
        foodButton.setText("ZZzz");
        prefs.edit().remove("foodTime").commit();
        buddy.setSleeping(true);
    }

    else
    {
        foodButton.setText("Awake");
        buddy.setSleeping(false);
    }
}
```

.

```
public void initBuddy()
{
    debugView.setText("FoodLevel: " + buddy.getFoodLevel());
    if(!buddy.getSleeping() && buddy.getAlive())
    {
        long currentTime = prefs.getLong("currentTime", getCurentTime());
        long foodTime = prefs.getLong("foodTime", getCurentTime());

        while (foodTime < currentTime)
        {
            if (currentTime - foodTime >= ONE_HOUR)
            {
                buddy.decayFood();
            }

            foodTime = foodTime + ONE_HOUR;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have the following two methods that get the current time and the close time (saved in onStop();) and i converted it to days/weeks/months/years. I want to check  how many nights there are between the closeTIme and the currentTIme but  I'm not sure what to do with the info. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
    public void checkSleepTimes()
{
    closeCalendar = timeHelper.convertLongToCal(loadCloseTime());
    closeArray = loadDateArrayList(closeArray, closeCalendar);

    currentCalendar = timeHelper.convertLongToCal(getCurentTime());
    closeArray = loadDateArrayList(currentArray, currentCalendar);

    long curTime = getCurentTime();
    int times = 0;
    long totalSleepTime = 0;
    while (closeTime < curTime)
    {
            closeTime = closeTime + WHOLE_DAY;
            times ++;

    }
    //TODO Check how many times it was between 08:00 and 20:00
    totalSleepTime = SLEEP_TIME * times; // not sure if correct approach
}

public ArrayList loadDateArrayList(ArrayList arrayList, Calendar calendar)
{
    arrayList.add(0,calendar.DATE);
    arrayList.add(1,calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    arrayList.add(2,calendar.MONTH);
    arrayList.add(3,calendar.YEAR);
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: It is easier to calculate full days when you have an integer. e.g. with integer containing hours fullDays=totalTime%24. However it seems your code is doing it already. If it works correctly, "times" should be number of full days.

Answer (score 1):

If the time since last feeding is longer than sleep time, check if the expected sleep period falls into that time. Then act accordingly (quick hack would be to add the sleep time to the time of last feeding). Also check if more than one day has passed since the feed time. Something like this:

```
if (currentTime - foodTime >= ONE_HOUR)
{
  if (currentTime - foodTime >= WHOLE_NIGHT &&   sleepPeriodFitsInBetween(foodTime, currentTime))
  {
    foodTime+=WHOLE_NIGHT;
    int numberOfFullDays=countNumberOfDays(currentTime - foodTime);
    if(numberOfFullDays>1)
    {
        currentTime+=numberOfFullDays*(24-WHOLE_HIGHT); // assuming WHOLE_NIGHT is in hours.

    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sound like a plan. only one question. what if i dont start the app for 2 days, wont the foodLVL stay the same? becouse 42 hours is larger than WHOLE_NIGHT.

Comment: This depends on how you set currentTime and foodTime. If they are eg. hours from some starting point, the only thing you need to do to add one WHOLE_NIGHT for every 24 hours.

Comment: Mmmm I'm a bit stuck. Wat I want to do is that when the app starts that it checks if it has been 20:00 sinds the last foodtime. to do that i want to use Calendar and save it to sharedPRefs if the feed method is used. Only I cant get the calendar in the prefs. I know I have to convert it to a long and than save the milliseconds but don't know how